# Get records with blank field value using LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am using a filter criteria to pull records where my table shows dynamic search results based on the input text. below is the code I am using -

```
Me.Bookbindingsource.Filter = *Book_Author LIKE '*" & TextBox.Text & "*'"
```

This field can be blank. When form loads, I want it to display all the records, but only those records are displayed which have atleast one character in the Author field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `where` clause. Use `OR` condition to accept the empty string

```
where (Book_Author LIKE '*" & TextBox.Text & "*' or Book_Author = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add where clause

```
where Book_Author LIKE '*" & TextBox.Text & "*' or Book_Author = ''
```

and if you have already other where clause then add

```
AND ( Book_Author LIKE '*" & TextBox.Text & "*' or Book_Author = '')
```

Comment: Actually this worked with little bit of moderation. Thanks.
I used - Book_Author is NULL